# How does the master bootstrap process work and how can I debug it?

Tags: yugabytedb

I am working to stand up 3 instances of the yugabyte master and tserver in separate k8s clusters connected over LoadBalancer services on bare metal. However, on all three master instances it looks like the bootstrap process is failing:

```
I0531 19:50:28.081645     1 master_main.cc:94] NumCPUs determined to be: 2
I0531 19:50:28.082594     1 server_base_options.cc:124] Updating master addrs to {yb-master-black.example.com:7100},{yb-master-blue.example.com:7100},{yb-master-white.example.com:7100},{:7100}
I0531 19:50:28.082682     1 server_base_options.cc:124] Updating master addrs to {yb-master-black.example.com:7100},{yb-master-blue.example.com:7100},{yb-master-white.example.com:7100},{:7100}
I0531 19:50:28.082937     1 mem_tracker.cc:249] MemTracker: hard memory limit is 1.699219 GB
I0531 19:50:28.082963     1 mem_tracker.cc:251] MemTracker: soft memory limit is 1.444336 GB
I0531 19:50:28.083189     1 server_base_options.cc:124] Updating master addrs to {yb-master-black.example.com:7100},{yb-master-blue.example.com:7100},{yb-master-white.example.com:7100},{:7100}
I0531 19:50:28.090148     1 server_base_options.cc:124] Updating master addrs to {yb-master-black.example.com:7100},{yb-master-blue.example.com:7100},{yb-master-white.example.com:7100},{:7100}
I0531 19:50:28.090863     1 rpc_server.cc:86] yb::server::RpcServer created at 0x1a7e210
I0531 19:50:28.090924     1 master.cc:146] yb::master::Master created at 0x7ffe2d4bd140
I0531 19:50:28.090958     1 master.cc:147] yb::master::TSManager created at 0x1a90850
I0531 19:50:28.090975     1 master.cc:148] yb::master::CatalogManager created at 0x1dea000
I0531 19:50:28.091152     1 master_main.cc:115] Initializing master server...
I0531 19:50:28.093097     1 server_base.cc:462] Could not load existing FS layout: Not found (yb/util/env_posix.cc:1482): /mnt/disk0/yb-data/master/instance: No such file or directory (system error 2)
I0531 19:50:28.093150     1 server_base.cc:463] Creating new FS layout
I0531 19:50:28.193439     1 fs_manager.cc:463] Generated new instance metadata in path /mnt/disk0/yb-data/master/instance:
uuid: "5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa"
format_stamp: "Formatted at 2020-05-31 19:50:28 on yb-master-0"
I0531 19:50:28.238484     1 fs_manager.cc:463] Generated new instance metadata in path /mnt/disk1/yb-data/master/instance:
uuid: "5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa"
format_stamp: "Formatted at 2020-05-31 19:50:28 on yb-master-0"
I0531 19:50:28.377483     1 fs_manager.cc:251] Opened local filesystem: /mnt/disk0,/mnt/disk1
uuid: "5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa"
format_stamp: "Formatted at 2020-05-31 19:50:28 on yb-master-0"
I0531 19:50:28.378015     1 server_base.cc:245] Auto setting FLAGS_num_reactor_threads to 2
I0531 19:50:28.380707     1 thread_pool.cc:166] Starting thread pool { name: Master queue_limit: 10000 max_workers: 1024 }
I0531 19:50:28.382266     1 master_main.cc:118] Starting Master server...
I0531 19:50:28.382313    24 async_initializer.cc:74] Starting to init ybclient
I0531 19:50:28.382365     1 master_main.cc:119] ulimit cur(max)...
ulimit: core file size unlimited(unlimited) blks
ulimit: data seg size unlimited(unlimited) kb
ulimit: open files 1048576(1048576)
ulimit: file size unlimited(unlimited) blks
ulimit: pending signals 22470(22470)
ulimit: file locks unlimited(unlimited)
ulimit: max locked memory 64(64) kb
ulimit: max memory size unlimited(unlimited) kb
ulimit: stack size 8192(unlimited) kb
ulimit: cpu time unlimited(unlimited) secs
ulimit: max user processes unlimited(unlimited)
W0531 19:50:28.383322    24 master.cc:186] Failed to get current config: Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
I0531 19:50:28.383525    24 client-internal.cc:1847] New master addresses: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100,yb-master-blue.example.com:7100,yb-master-white.example.com:7100,:7100]
I0531 19:50:28.383685     1 service_pool.cc:148] yb.master.MasterBackupService: yb::rpc::ServicePoolImpl created at 0x1a82b40
I0531 19:50:28.384888     1 service_pool.cc:148] yb.master.MasterService: yb::rpc::ServicePoolImpl created at 0x1a83680
I0531 19:50:28.385342     1 service_pool.cc:148] yb.tserver.TabletServerService: yb::rpc::ServicePoolImpl created at 0x1a838c0
I0531 19:50:28.388526     1 thread_pool.cc:166] Starting thread pool { name: Master-high-pri queue_limit: 10000 max_workers: 1024 }
I0531 19:50:28.388588     1 service_pool.cc:148] yb.consensus.ConsensusService: yb::rpc::ServicePoolImpl created at 0x201eb40
I0531 19:50:28.393231     1 service_pool.cc:148] yb.tserver.RemoteBootstrapService: yb::rpc::ServicePoolImpl created at 0x201ed80
I0531 19:50:28.393501     1 webserver.cc:148] Starting webserver on 0.0.0.0:7000
I0531 19:50:28.393544     1 webserver.cc:153] Document root: /home/yugabyte/www
I0531 19:50:28.394471     1 webserver.cc:240] Webserver started. Bound to: http://0.0.0.0:7000/
I0531 19:50:28.394668     1 service_pool.cc:148] yb.server.GenericService: yb::rpc::ServicePoolImpl created at 0x201efc0
I0531 19:50:28.395015     1 rpc_server.cc:169] RPC server started. Bound to: 0.0.0.0:7100
I0531 19:50:28.420223    23 tcp_stream.cc:308] { local: 10.233.80.35:55710 remote: 172.16.0.34:7100 }:  Recv failed: Network error (yb/util/net/socket.cc:537): recvmsg error: Connection refused (system error 111)
E0531 19:51:28.523921    24 async_initializer.cc:84] Failed to initialize client: Timed out (yb/rpc/rpc.cc:213): Could not locate the leader master: GetLeaderMasterRpc(addrs: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, :7100], num_attempts: 293) passed its deadline 2074493.105s (passed: 60.140s): Not found (yb/master/master_rpc.cc:284): no leader found: GetLeaderMasterRpc(addrs: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, :7100], num_attempts: 1)
W0531 19:51:29.524827    24 master.cc:186] Failed to get current config: Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
I0531 19:51:29.524914    24 client-internal.cc:1847] New master addresses: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100,yb-master-blue.example.com:7100,yb-master-white.example.com:7100,:7100]
E0531 19:52:29.524785    24 async_initializer.cc:84] Failed to initialize client: Timed out (yb/rpc/outbound_call.cc:512): Could not locate the leader master: GetMasterRegistration RPC (request call id 2359) to 172.29.1.1:7100 timed out after 0.033s
W0531 19:52:30.525079    24 master.cc:186] Failed to get current config: Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
I0531 19:52:30.525205    24 client-internal.cc:1847] New master addresses: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100,yb-master-blue.example.com:7100,yb-master-white.example.com:7100,:7100]
W0531 19:53:28.114395    36 master-path-handlers.cc:150] Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Unable to list Masters: Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
W0531 19:53:29.133951    36 master-path-handlers.cc:1002] Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Unable to list Masters: Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
E0531 19:53:30.625366    24 async_initializer.cc:84] Failed to initialize client: Timed out (yb/rpc/rpc.cc:213): Could not locate the leader master: GetLeaderMasterRpc(addrs: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, :7100], num_attempts: 299) passed its deadline 2074615.247s (passed: 60.099s): Not found (yb/master/master_rpc.cc:284): no leader found: GetLeaderMasterRpc(addrs: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, :7100], num_attempts: 1)
W0531 19:53:31.625660    24 master.cc:186] Failed to get current config: Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
I0531 19:53:31.625742    24 client-internal.cc:1847] New master addresses: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100,yb-master-blue.example.com:7100,yb-master-white.example.com:7100,:7100]
W0531 19:53:34.024369    37 master-path-handlers.cc:150] Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Unable to list Masters: Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
E0531 19:54:31.870801    24 async_initializer.cc:84] Failed to initialize client: Timed out (yb/rpc/rpc.cc:213): Could not locate the leader master: GetLeaderMasterRpc(addrs: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, :7100], num_attempts: 300) passed its deadline 2074676.348s (passed: 60.244s): Not found (yb/master/master_rpc.cc:284): no leader found: GetLeaderMasterRpc(addrs: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, :7100], num_attempts: 1)
W0531 19:54:32.871065    24 master.cc:186] Failed to get current config: Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
I0531 19:54:32.871222    24 client-internal.cc:1847] New master addresses: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100,yb-master-blue.example.com:7100,yb-master-white.example.com:7100,:7100]
W0531 19:55:28.190217    41 master-path-handlers.cc:1002] Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Unable to list Masters: Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
W0531 19:55:31.745038    42 master-path-handlers.cc:1002] Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Unable to list Masters: Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
E0531 19:55:33.164300    24 async_initializer.cc:84] Failed to initialize client: Timed out (yb/rpc/rpc.cc:213): Could not locate the leader master: GetLeaderMasterRpc(addrs: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, :7100], num_attempts: 299) passed its deadline 2074737.593s (passed: 60.292s): Not found (yb/master/master_rpc.cc:284): no leader found: GetLeaderMasterRpc(addrs: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, :7100], num_attempts: 1)
W0531 19:55:34.164574    24 master.cc:186] Failed to get current config: Illegal state (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:6854): Node 5f2f6ad78d27450b8cde9c8bcf40fefa peer not initialized.
I0531 19:55:34.164667    24 client-internal.cc:1847] New master addresses: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100,yb-master-blue.example.com:7100,yb-master-white.example.com:7100,:7100]
E0531 19:56:34.315380    24 async_initializer.cc:84] Failed to initialize client: Timed out (yb/rpc/rpc.cc:213): Could not locate the leader master: GetLeaderMasterRpc(addrs: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, :7100], num_attempts: 299) passed its deadline 2074798.886s (passed: 60.150s): Not found (yb/master/master_rpc.cc:284): no leader found: GetLeaderMasterRpc(addrs: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, :7100], num_attempts: 1)
```

As far as connectivity goes, I am able to verify the LoadBalancer endpoints are responding across the different network boundaries by curling the same service endpoint but on the UI port:

```
[root@yb-master-0 yugabyte]# curl -I http://yb-master-blue.example.com:7000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1975
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

[root@yb-master-0 yugabyte]# curl -I http://yb-master-white.example.com:7000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1975
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

[root@yb-master-0 yugabyte]# curl -I http://yb-master-black.example.com:7000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1975
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

What strategies are there to debug the bootstrap process?

EDIT:
Here are the startup flags for the master:

```
/home/yugabyte/bin/yb-master --fs_data_dirs=/mnt/disk0,/mnt/disk1 --server_broadcast_addresses=yb-master-white.example.com:7100 --master_addresses=yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, --replication_factor=3 --enable_ysql=true --rpc_bind_addresses=0.0.0.0:7100 --metric_node_name=yb-master-0 --memory_limit_hard_bytes=1824522240 --stderrthreshold=0 --num_cpus=2 --undefok=num_cpus,enable_ysql --default_memory_limit_to_ram_ratio=0.85 --leader_failure_max_missed_heartbeat_periods=10 --placement_cloud=AAAA --placement_region=XXXX --placement_zone=XXXX

/home/yugabyte/bin/yb-master --fs_data_dirs=/mnt/disk0,/mnt/disk1 --server_broadcast_addresses=yb-master-blue.example.com:7100 --master_addresses=yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, --replication_factor=3 --enable_ysql=true --rpc_bind_addresses=0.0.0.0:7100 --metric_node_name=yb-master-0 --memory_limit_hard_bytes=1824522240 --stderrthreshold=0 --num_cpus=2 --undefok=num_cpus,enable_ysql --default_memory_limit_to_ram_ratio=0.85 --leader_failure_max_missed_heartbeat_periods=10 --placement_cloud=AAAA --placement_region=YYYY --placement_zone=YYYY

/home/yugabyte/bin/yb-master --fs_data_dirs=/mnt/disk0,/mnt/disk1 --server_broadcast_addresses=yb-master-black.example.com:7100 --master_addresses=yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100,  --replication_factor=3 --enable_ysql=true --rpc_bind_addresses=0.0.0.0:7100 --metric_node_name=yb-master-0 --memory_limit_hard_bytes=1824522240 --stderrthreshold=0 --num_cpus=2 --undefok=num_cpus,enable_ysql --default_memory_limit_to_ram_ratio=0.85 --leader_failure_max_missed_heartbeat_periods=10 --placement_cloud=AAAA --placement_region=ZZZZ --placement_zone=ZZZZ
```

For the sake of completeness here is one of the k8s manifest that I've modified from one of the helm examples. It is modified to utilize LoadBalancer for the master service:

```
---
# Source: yugabyte/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "yb-masters"
  labels:
    app: "yb-master"
    heritage: "Helm"
    release: "blue"
    chart: "yugabyte"
    component: "yugabytedb"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 172.16.0.34
  ports:
    - name: "rpc-port"
      port: 7100
    - name: "ui"
      port: 7000
  selector:
    app: "yb-master"
---
# Source: yugabyte/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "yb-tservers"
  labels:
    app: "yb-tserver"
    heritage: "Helm"
    release: "blue"
    chart: "yugabyte"
    component: "yugabytedb"
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: "rpc-port"
      port: 7100
    - name: "ui"
      port: 9000
    - name: "yedis-port"
      port: 6379
    - name: "yql-port"
      port: 9042
    - name: "ysql-port"
      port: 5433
  selector:
    app: "yb-tserver"
---
# Source: yugabyte/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: "yb-master"
  namespace: "yugabytedb"
  labels:
    app: "yb-master"
    heritage: "Helm"
    release: "blue"
    chart: "yugabyte"
    component: "yugabytedb"
spec:
  serviceName: "yb-masters"
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel

  replicas: 1

  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: datadir0
        annotations:
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: rook-ceph-block
        labels:
          heritage: "Helm"
          release: "blue"
          chart: "yugabyte"
          component: "yugabytedb"
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - "ReadWriteOnce"
        storageClassName: rook-ceph-block
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
    - metadata:
        name: datadir1
        annotations:
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: rook-ceph-block
        labels:
          heritage: "Helm"
          release: "blue"
          chart: "yugabyte"
          component: "yugabytedb"
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - "ReadWriteOnce"
        storageClassName: rook-ceph-block
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:

      partition: 0

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "yb-master"
  template:
    metadata:

      labels:
        app: "yb-master"
        heritage: "Helm"
        release: "blue"
        chart: "yugabyte"
        component: "yugabytedb"
    spec:
      affinity:
        # Set the anti-affinity selector scope to YB masters.

        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - "yb-master"
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
      - name: "yb-master"
        image: "yugabytedb/yugabyte:2.1.6.0-b17"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command:
                - "sh"
                - "-c"
                - >
                  mkdir -p /mnt/disk0/cores;
                  mkdir -p /mnt/disk0/yb-data/scripts;
                  if [ ! -f /mnt/disk0/yb-data/scripts/log_cleanup.sh ]; then
                    if [ -f /home/yugabyte/bin/log_cleanup.sh ]; then
                      cp /home/yugabyte/bin/log_cleanup.sh /mnt/disk0/yb-data/scripts;
                    fi;
                  fi
        env:
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: HOSTNAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        resources:

          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1Gi

        command:

          - "/home/yugabyte/bin/yb-master"

          - "--fs_data_dirs=/mnt/disk0,/mnt/disk1"

          - "--server_broadcast_addresses=yb-master-blue.example.com:7100"

          - "--master_addresses=yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, "
          - "--replication_factor=3"


          - "--enable_ysql=true"
          - "--rpc_bind_addresses=0.0.0.0:7100"
          - "--metric_node_name=$(HOSTNAME)"
          - "--memory_limit_hard_bytes=1824522240"
          - "--stderrthreshold=0"
          - "--num_cpus=2"
          - "--undefok=num_cpus,enable_ysql"
          - "--default_memory_limit_to_ram_ratio=0.85"
          - "--leader_failure_max_missed_heartbeat_periods=10"
          - "--placement_cloud=AAAA"
          - "--placement_region=YYYY"
          - "--placement_zone=YYYY"

        ports:
          - containerPort: 7100
            name: "rpc-port"
          - containerPort: 7000
            name: "ui"
        volumeMounts:

          - name: datadir0
            mountPath: /mnt/disk0
          - name: datadir1
            mountPath: /mnt/disk1

      - name: yb-cleanup
        image: busybox:1.31
        env:
        - name: USER
          value: "yugabyte"
        command:
          - "/bin/sh"
          - "-c"
          - >
            mkdir /var/spool/cron;
            mkdir /var/spool/cron/crontabs;
            echo "0 * * * * /home/yugabyte/scripts/log_cleanup.sh" | tee -a /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root;
            crond;
            while true; do
              sleep 86400;
            done
        volumeMounts:
          - name: datadir0
            mountPath: /home/yugabyte/
            subPath: yb-data

      volumes:

        - name: datadir0
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt/disks/ssd0
        - name: datadir1
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt/disks/ssd1
---
# Source: yugabyte/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: "yb-tserver"
  namespace: "yugabytedb"
  labels:
    app: "yb-tserver"
    heritage: "Helm"
    release: "blue"
    chart: "yugabyte"
    component: "yugabytedb"
spec:
  serviceName: "yb-tservers"
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel

  replicas: 1

  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: datadir0
        annotations:
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: rook-ceph-block
        labels:
          heritage: "Helm"
          release: "blue"
          chart: "yugabyte"
          component: "yugabytedb"
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - "ReadWriteOnce"
        storageClassName: rook-ceph-block
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
    - metadata:
        name: datadir1
        annotations:
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: rook-ceph-block
        labels:
          heritage: "Helm"
          release: "blue"
          chart: "yugabyte"
          component: "yugabytedb"
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - "ReadWriteOnce"
        storageClassName: rook-ceph-block
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:

      partition: 0

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "yb-tserver"
  template:
    metadata:

      labels:
        app: "yb-tserver"
        heritage: "Helm"
        release: "blue"
        chart: "yugabyte"
        component: "yugabytedb"
    spec:
      affinity:
        # Set the anti-affinity selector scope to YB masters.

        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - "yb-tserver"
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
      - name: "yb-tserver"
        image: "yugabytedb/yugabyte:2.1.6.0-b17"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command:
                - "sh"
                - "-c"
                - >
                  mkdir -p /mnt/disk0/cores;
                  mkdir -p /mnt/disk0/yb-data/scripts;
                  if [ ! -f /mnt/disk0/yb-data/scripts/log_cleanup.sh ]; then
                    if [ -f /home/yugabyte/bin/log_cleanup.sh ]; then
                      cp /home/yugabyte/bin/log_cleanup.sh /mnt/disk0/yb-data/scripts;
                    fi;
                  fi
        env:
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: HOSTNAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        resources:

          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 4Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 2Gi

        command:

          - "/home/yugabyte/bin/yb-tserver"
          - "--fs_data_dirs=/mnt/disk0,/mnt/disk1"
          - "--server_broadcast_addresses=$(HOSTNAME).yb-tservers.$(NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local:9100"
          - "--rpc_bind_addresses=$(HOSTNAME).yb-tservers.$(NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local"
          - "--cql_proxy_bind_address=$(HOSTNAME).yb-tservers.$(NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local"

          - "--enable_ysql=true"
          - "--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=$(POD_IP):5433"


          - "--tserver_master_addrs=yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100, "

          - "--metric_node_name=$(HOSTNAME)"
          - "--memory_limit_hard_bytes=3649044480"
          - "--stderrthreshold=0"
          - "--num_cpus=2"
          - "--undefok=num_cpus,enable_ysql"
          - "--leader_failure_max_missed_heartbeat_periods=10"
          - "--placement_cloud=AAAA"
          - "--placement_region=YYYY"
          - "--placement_zone=YYYY"
          - "--use_cassandra_authentication=false"

        ports:
          - containerPort: 7100
            name: "rpc-port"
          - containerPort: 9000
            name: "ui"
          - containerPort: 6379
            name: "yedis-port"
          - containerPort: 9042
            name: "yql-port"
          - containerPort: 5433
            name: "ysql-port"
        volumeMounts:

          - name: datadir0
            mountPath: /mnt/disk0
          - name: datadir1
            mountPath: /mnt/disk1


      - name: yb-cleanup
        image: busybox:1.31
        env:
        - name: USER
          value: "yugabyte"
        command:
          - "/bin/sh"
          - "-c"
          - >
            mkdir /var/spool/cron;
            mkdir /var/spool/cron/crontabs;
            echo "0 * * * * /home/yugabyte/scripts/log_cleanup.sh" | tee -a /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root;
            crond;
            while true; do
              sleep 86400;
            done
        volumeMounts:
          - name: datadir0
            mountPath: /home/yugabyte/
            subPath: yb-data

      volumes:

        - name: datadir0
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt/disks/ssd0
        - name: datadir1
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt/disks/ssd1
```

Comment: hi @zanegray: 

Can you share the command line arguments or the gflag file passed to yb-master processes please?

Comment: hi @zanegray: Also, noticed the following in the log file:


```
client-internal.cc:1847] New master addresses: [yb-master-black.example.com:7100,yb-master-blue.example.com:7100,yb-master-white.example.com:7100,:7100]
```

Notice that the above has 4 entries -- but last entry doesn't have a hostname and it is just ":7100". Is that a typo. Normally, for replication factor 3, we would expect the master addresses to have 3 entries (and not 4).

Comment: @KannanMuthukkaruppan I've updated the OP with the process flags. The extraneous fourth master address looked off to me as well, but I'm not sure why it is there as I've only specified three hosts. Is that an implicit localhost?

Comment: You know what, it looks like there is an extraneous comma. Probably an artifact of the helm templating process. Let me fix that and try again.

Answer (score 2):

This was mostly resolved (looks like I've now run into an unrelated issue), by dropping the extraneous comma on the master addresses list:

```
--master_addresses=yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100,
```

vs

```
--master_addresses=yb-master-black.example.com:7100, yb-master-blue.example.com:7100, yb-master-white.example.com:7100
```